# How to detect access control machine in or out?

Tags: c#

I have different types of access machines like fingerprint scanner, card scanner, etc. These machines generate a data when used like card_no:punch_time.

I am developing an app in C#.NET to manage these access. Employees scan their cards while in and out. They have 3 or more different working shifts. But I have a problem with how do I detect if they are entering or leaving without using any hardware?

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

For your *Without using any hardware* situation, one way is to develop a web-based Attendance management application, make it accessible from a LAN enabled PC, it will just provide GUI for entering their credentials and will store the information in a database present at some other PC, employees will have to Sign-in at the start of their shifts and will have to Sign-out while leaving the office.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But there are 2500 employees entering and leaving within 10 minutes. I think this process will make it 2 hours or more...